# Android: getting different latitude and longitude on same location

Tags: android, google-maps

We are making track and trace application and for this accuracy of address is very important for us.

we have done testing of our application and found that we are getting different latitude and longitude for same location.if there is slightly change in the latitude and longitude then accuracy of address is about 150 to 200 meters away from actual location.

my question is why i am getting different latitude and longitude for the same location??  what i can do to get more accurate latitude and longitude??

Thanks,
Sanjay Salunkhe

Comment: can you show some snippet??

Comment: @ArpitPatel - i am not android developer. so can't share the code with you.

Comment: What are you using to get the location?! NETWORK or GPS?!

Comment: i am using GPS to get the location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used Fused Location API [HERE](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html) is the tutorial.

When working with location, it is important to understand that you may request a certain accuracy, but **you're not guaranteed to get that accuracy in actual location updates**.

Here is the accuracy table which is tested by google See Presentation [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc)

[image]

In your case there is something wrong in your code otherwise it will not give away 150-200 m because that is huge distance.

Comment: i am not android developer but can you guess what could be the wrong in the code??